# weka wrapper attribute selection random forest java

Tags: java, attributes, selection, weka, feature-selection

```
protected static void attSelection_w(Instances data) throws Exception { 
    AttributeSelection fs = new AttributeSelection();
    WrapperSubsetEval wrapper = new WrapperSubsetEval();

    wrapper.buildEvaluator(data);
    wrapper.setClassifier(new RandomForest());
    wrapper.setFolds(10);
    wrapper.setThreshold(0.001);

    fs.SelectAttributes(data);  
    fs.setEvaluator(wrapper);
    fs.setSearch(new BestFirst());
    System.out.println(fs.toResultsString());
}
```

Above is my code for wrapper based attribute selection using random forest + bestfirst search. However, this somehow spits out a result using cfs, like below.

```
Search Method:
    Greedy Stepwise (forwards).
    Start set: no attributes
    Merit of best subset found:    0.287

Attribute Subset Evaluator (supervised, Class (nominal): 9 class):
    CFS Subset Evaluator
    Including locally predictive attributes
```

There is no other code using CFS in the whole class, and I'm pretty much stuck.. I would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You just inverted the order and get the default method, the correct order is to set the parameter first, then call the selection:

```
//first  
fs.setEvaluator(wrapper);
fs.setSearch(new BestFirst());
//then
fs.SelectAttributes(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set class Index and add this line after creating instance data

```
data.setClassIndex(data.numAttributes() - 1);
```

I checked and it worked fine.